# Setting text background color?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, look-and-feel, nimbus

How can I set text background color in `JOptionPane`?

Image:

[image]

```
UIManager UI = new UIManager();
UI.put("OptionPane.background", Color.white);
UIManager.put("Button.background", Color.white);
UI.put("Panel.background", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.foreground", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.messagebackground", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.textbackground", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.warningDialog.titlePane.shadow", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.warningDialog.border.background", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.warningDialog.titlePane.background", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.warningDialog.titlePane.foreground", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.questionDialog.border.background", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.questionDialog.titlePane.background", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.questionDialog.titlePane.foreground", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.questionDialog.titlePane.shadow", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.messageForeground", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.foreground", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.errorDialog.border.background", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.errorDialog.titlePane.background", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.errorDialog.titlePane.foreground", Color.white);
UI.put("OptionPane.errorDialog.titlePane.shadow", Color.white);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello world", "HELLO WORLD", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Has your problem been resolved? If so please post what you did as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not you simply add a custom `JPanel` at this place as shown below :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, getLabelPanel(), "Hello World!",
                                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

You can get the `JPanel` from a method, like :

```
private JPanel getLabelPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setOpaque(true);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    JLabel helloLabel = new JLabel("Hello World!", JLabel.CENTER);
    helloLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.add(helloLabel);

    return panel;
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image: PANEIMAGE]

---

### UPDATE 1 :

Else you can try this to change everything,

```
uimanager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.BLUE);
uimanager.put("OptionPane.messagebackground", Color.BLUE);
uimanager.put("Panel.background", Color.BLUE);
```

UPDATED OUTPUT :

[image: OPTIONPANEIMAGE]

Comment: @user2464161 : If this is not what you wanted, why not use a `JDialog`, that way you don't really need to play with the `UIManager` and work out a solution without any fuss.

Comment: I believe the question explicitly asks for a way to change the background color of a JOptionPane not a way around it.

Comment: @DustinE. : Its just an alternative I suggested. Sometimes what one is thinking, might not be the right track. So its about ideas that one gets from others, that the same thingy can be achieved through other means too :-) Though taken your advice, and updated likewise :-)

Comment: @mKorbel : Ahha, I just got, you were referring to the OP's side `LookAndFeel`.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
UIManager UI=new UIManager();
 UI.put("OptionPane.background",new ColorUIResource(255,255,0));
 UI.put("Panel.background",new ColorUIResource(255,255,0));
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it did not help, it's still the same

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest would be using JDialog to create your own JOptionPane replacement, like nIcE cOw suggested. `JOptionPane` packs a lot of junk in its frame, and several of the components check no `JOptionPane` specific properties at all.

If you insist on using JOptionPane anyway, and want to change the background for only those, not for everything in the application, I'd say that if you want to set the background for the entire dialog with all its subcomponents, your best bet is to iterate all the window contents and call `setBackground()` on each. That could be done in its UI class, or individually for dialogs obtained with `JOptionPane.createDialog()`. Roughly like this:

```
void colorComponentTree(Component component, Color color) {
    if (component instanceof Container) {
        if (component instanceof JComponent) {
             ((JComponent) component).setBackground(color);
        }

        for (Component child : ((Container) component).getComponents()) {
             colorComponentTree(child, color);
        }
    }
}
```

That is however *really* ugly and I seriously recommend taking the custom dialog route.